Flutter suggests invalid imports
Has anyone had a problem where flutter and vscode suggest imports from files that actually import the needed file? The initial file is just an extension class, but flutter keeps suggesting files that are importing the actual context extension file, idk what is happeningFlutter import suggestions,The file that imports extension fileThe initial extension file
I've tried to create separate export file, but that dosen't resolve the issue and the thing is, that vs-code quick-fix is actually suggesting the proper file, but when i'm writing code flutter auto suggest invalid files

Have you tried restarting the analyzer?  Or even restarting VSCode?  Occasionally the analyzer seems to get a bit out of sync.

@RandalSchwartz I've tried that, but that dosen't seem to help. I've event tried to use my other PC to check if it's vs code issue, but the issue is still there

I've experienced this before but because I added several places in the codebase where I exported specific files, maybe that's your issue?

I guess that these fixes are not on the stable dart channel yet @RezaFarjam?

@LDR Yes, the fix is not available on stable channel yet.
